# How to remove spacing between the top of a border and a div

Tags: javascript, html, css, padding

I currently have a div that is displaying a chart. In my HTML page, I have given it the ID of "main". In my CSS, I am trying to bring the chart a bit more up in the page, however, have had issues. I currently have a border, and am trying to bring the chart up to the border. In other words, I won't want any padding/space between the div and the top of the border. This is how it looks like right now:

[image: Example of too much space/padding]

And here is how my CSS code looks like right now:

```
#main {                     
        position:relative;          
        width:95%;                  
        left:3%;              
        border: 3px solid green;
        padding-top: 0px;   
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: could you please reproduce the issue in a fiddle or so..

Comment: margin: 0; ? use a snippet please

Comment: Is the `div` the only element inside of `body`? Then the body may get a margin by browser default. Try `body { margin: 0; }`

Comment: Exactly, it has to do with margin... but it also depends on whether or not chart image itself has any margin or padding.  You can get hacky and use negative margin but I wouldn't recommend it. You could also try adjusting the height of the div.

Comment: There is a div and then there is a header at the top. So it is not the only element of body

Comment: I've adjusted the height but the padding remains the same.

Comment: When I do absolute positioning, the chart just goes away. I think it may have to do with the charting library, because other libraries worked fine instantly. For now, I will just use a negative percentage for margin-top. Thanks!

Comment: Figured it out. It was because the chart had a legend and I had chosen not to display it. So the extra room was technically an "invisible" legend. Silly mistake!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try applying negative `marging` or negative `top` to your chart container...
Ex:

```
#main {                     
        position:relative;          
        width:95%;                  
        left:3%;              
        border: 3px solid green;
        padding-top: 0px;  
top:-20px 
}
```

or

```
#main {                     
        position:relative;          
        width:95%;                  
        left:3%;              
        border: 3px solid green;
        padding-top: 0px;  
margin-top:-20px; 
}
```

Comment: That did it. Thanks!

Comment: Aint it more interesting to figure out, what's the reason of this downward position and fix this?

Comment: you are welcome man! :)